# Erro na execução do django-admin.py no django 1.9

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin, django-1.9

Estou tentando aprender django e gostaria de entender essa notificação que recebo toda vez que executo o comando django-admin!

> Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).

uso python 2.7 e django 1.9. Alguem poderia dar uma luz?

Comment: coloca a sua arvore de diretorios do projeto e o arquivo settings.py, isso é um erro de configuração

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode rodar `django-admin startproject mysite` (Note que não é o django-admin.py), pois se o Django foi instalado pelo pip, existe um executável em C:/Python34/Scripts que já está em sua variável de ambiente "PATH"(se não estiver, o adicione assim funcionará o script)